# Append a div without refreshing jquery

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, content-management-system

I want to add a div without refreshing the page.

Here is my Javascript:

```
<input class="btnsubmit"  type="button" value="+Add Trivia" id="add_triviamodal"> 

function add_trivia()
{
    var PHOTO_TRIVIA = CKEDITOR.instances.Trivia_Photo.getData();
    var TITLE_TRIVIA = $('#TRIVIA_TITLE').val();
    var CAPTION_TRIVIA = CKEDITOR.instances.triviacap.getData();

$.post('insert_home.php',{TRIVIA_TITLE:TITLE_TRIVIA,TRIVIA_PHOTO:PHOTO_TRIVIA,TRIVIA_CAP:CAPTION_TRIVIA}).done(function(data){
    alert ("Trivia Successfully Added");
        location.reload(); \\what i do is just refresh the page
    });
}
```

This is how i output the the data that will be added using the ajax above

```
 echo "<div class=\"view view-sixth\">

              ".$Tri_IMAGE."


             <div class=\"mask\">
             <div class=\"divbutton\">
             <input  onclick='TRIVIA_EDIT($Tri_ID);' class=\"btnsubmit\"  type=\"button\" value=\"Edit\" id=\"edit_trivia\">
             <input  onclick='TRIVIA_DELETE($Tri_ID,this);' class=\"btnsubmit\"  type=\"button\" value=\"Delete\" id=\"delete_trivia\">
             </div> 
             <h2>".$Tri_TITLE."</h2>
             <p>".$Tri_CAPTION."</p>
             </div>
            </div>";
}
```

Comment: I edited your post slightly to make it less confusing. Please correct it if I made any mistakes.

Comment: Also, I'm assuming that the output of the AJAX call is what you want to append somewhere, correct?

Comment: No sir. :) the php scipt at the bottom will be the output of the ajax above.

Comment: it seems to me you don't need to use PHP/AJAX at all.

Comment: can you give me an answer on how to append a new div. Thanks

Comment: @user3196424 That's what I meant. AJAX is used to accesses the PHP script, so the output of that PHP script will be appended to your <div>.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `append()` in jQuery to append elements to the DOM. If the div is returned by your PHP. Then append it to a DOM element by using i.e. `$('#trivias').append(data);`

EDIT (using the question authors code as an example):

I've replaced the `location.reload()` part with the code to append the returning div.

```
$.post('insert_home.php',{TRIVIA_TITLE:TITLE_TRIVIA,TRIVIA_PHOTO:PHOTO_TRIVIA,TRIVIA_CAP:CAPTION_TRIVIA}).done(function(data){
  $('#trivias').append(data);
}
```

Here I assume you've got a element with the **trivias** id. For example `<div id="trivias">...</div>` somewhere in your code already.

Answer (score 0):

just put your response data into whatever you want it in

```
$.post('insert_home.php',{TRIVIA_TITLE:TITLE_TRIVIA,TRIVIA_PHOTO:PHOTO_TRIVIA,TRIVIA_CAP:CAPTION_TRIVIA}).done(function(data){
        alert ("Trivia Successfully Added");
        $('#idOfTheDivYouwantToPutResponseIn').html(data);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your $.post() callback to also append the HTML response from insert_home.php into the DIV.

```
$.post('insert_home.php',{
    TRIVIA_TITLE: TITLE_TRIVIA,
    TRIVIA_PHOTO: PHOTO_TRIVIA,
    TRIVIA_CAP: CAPTION_TRIVIA
}).done(function(data){
    alert ("Trivia Successfully Added");
    $('#trivias').html(data);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

in PHP use `json_encode`

```
$str = "<div class=\"view view-sixth\">
         ".$Tri_IMAGE."
             <div class=\"mask\">
             <div class=\"divbutton\">
             <input  onclick='TRIVIA_EDIT($Tri_ID);' class=\"btnsubmit\"  type=\"button\" value=\"Edit\" id=\"edit_trivia\">
             <input  onclick='TRIVIA_DELETE($Tri_ID,this);' class=\"btnsubmit\"  type=\"button\" value=\"Delete\" id=\"delete_trivia\">
             </div> 
             <h2>".$Tri_TITLE."</h2>
             <p>".$Tri_CAPTION."</p>
             </div>
            </div>";

echo json_encode($str);
```

then use he post request like this

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'insert_home.php',
    data: {TRIVIA_TITLE:TITLE_TRIVIA,TRIVIA_PHOTO:PHOTO_TRIVIA,TRIVIA_CAP:CAPTION_TRIVIA},
    dataType:'json',
    success: function (data) {
         $('#your_id').html(data);
    }
});
```